# SQL Server Express 2014 Installation directory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms, sql-server-express

I face recently a problem when starting SQL Server Management Studio. As it can't start, I uninstall it. When trying to install it again, I am asked to select the installation folder of SQL Server.

[image: Browse for SQL Server 2014 Installation media]

Unfortunately, nor the `MSSQL` folder, nor its `Binn` child solved my problem. Can somebody help get the right folder ?

**Edit :** 
I've succeeded installing `SSMS` again, but I still can not run it. It is showing this message : 
[image: Error message when starting SSMS]

Finally, I cannot guess the source of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

That dialog asks you for the installation **media**, pay attention. You need to specify the location from where you've run the original install. That is not an Express uninstall, you are uninstalling a licensed SSMS, so you should provide your original, licensed, CDs.

Answer (score 0):

You are out on deep water here.. never uninstall SSMS without taking the entire (local) SQL Server installation out of PC (I don't assume you are acting like this on a server!). Next time, *begin with* using the SQL Server Installation Center to fix and repair your issues - or dig deeper on the internet before doing anything rash.

As to the situation at hand: Per [this thread on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/09e9bd54-9d45-4571-a267-7b6f3cfbca67/how-can-find-out-that-selected-installation-media-are-for-edition-enterprise-or-standard?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade), every media holds all versions, it is the license which make the distinguishing. So: Find the installation file (e.g. SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe) on the machine, and run it! This will take you through the repair/installation process without the need to point to the installation media (which is supposed to be a physical DVD or iso image).
If you have deleted the installation file since the first install, just download a new one from [Microsoft Download Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx).